# Vision.VNRecognizeTextRequest in Xamarin iOS 13

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios13, vision

Does anyone know if Xamarin iOS has support for Vision.VNRecognizeTextRequest. I came across a old post https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6830 which says it is not available in Xamarin iOS 13.
What is the latest status?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the issue it seems to be fixed and there are also two Xamarin samples on GitHub using `VNRecognizeTextRequest`, as you can see [here](https://github.com/brad302/Xamarin/blob/7d3c891021d0a2c564d3ba0f6b1853d97c83be3c/CameraVision/CameraVision.iOS/Renderers/CameraVisionRenderer.cs) and [here](https://github.com/prmallic/ReadingPhoneNumbersInRealTime/blob/0920ee31362f4b2ba5aebf31b02f2777c6873dd7/ReadingPhoneNumbersInRealTime/VisionViewController.cs).